# Add margin to PDF footer when using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments, wkhtmltopdf, ashx

I am using `wkhtmltopdf` to create pdf documents on the filesystem.
The PDFs generate fine when I insert arguments like this:

```
psi.Arguments = "- --footer-html "http://localhost/pdf/footerpage.html" --footer-right "Page [page] of [toPage]" "C:\PDF\pdf.pdf""
```

The problem is that the footer contains an image that does not fit. When I try to add a margin to the bottom like this:

```
psi.Arguments = "- --margin-bottom 30 --footer-html "http://localhost/pdf/footerpage.html" --footer-right "Page [page] of [toPage]" "C:\PDF\pdf.pdf""
```

the pdf cannot generate. The error: "--margin-bottom specified in incorrect location"
I found this on the wiki https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=957 but it did not help.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you escaping the quotes in the arguments passed? Or is this copied from your code?

Comment: Yes, I am using escaping in my code

Answer (score 0):

*Too big for a comment, so posting this as an answer.*

My experiments have indicated that `wkhtmltopdf` is particular about the order of arguments specified. Same is also noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12422348/326543).

Sounds so strange, I am quite convinced that I am doing something wrong.

Can you try this -

```
psi.Arguments = "- --footer-html \"http://localhost/pdf/footerpage.html\" --footer-right \"Page [page] of [toPage]\" --margin-bottom 30 \"C:\PDF\pdf.pdf\""
```

Comment: No luck when changing the order of the arguments